# Is there a more efficient way of checking if an element is inside given intervals?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a variable x (double) that lies between 0 and 100. If x is in any of the intervals (0+10*n,5+10*n), with n (int) =0,...,9, then I return n, otherwise I break. I was thinking of doing this

```
bool test = false;
int k;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

    if((0+10*i)<x<(5+10*i)){
        k = i;
        test = true;
    }
}

if(test) return k;
else break;
```

would this be correct? If so, is there any other way that avoids loops?

Comment: If the data type of `x` matters, you should indicate what it is in the question.

Comment: @Brilliand My apologizes, I thought it was understood

Comment: Did you identify any problem with your code, that would suggest your code being slow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends which intervals you have in mind.  Since your intervals have a pattern to them, you can use a mathematical formula instead of a loop:

```
if(((int)x % 10) < 5) return (int)(x / 10);
else break;
```

(The `%` here is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).)

Since C++'s `%` operator doesn't work on doubles, you can either cast `x` to an integer (as shown), or use the `fmod` function (works for non-integer intervals).

Comment: @DMH16 C++ has an "fmod" function that provides modulus on floats.  Or you could cast x to an integer for this check, since the ranges are integer ranges anyway.

Comment: I do not think that would work. If x=3.21, for example, then 3%10=3. So from your code x lies in (30,35), instead x lies in the interval (0,5).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201489/discussion-between-brilliand-and-dmh16).

Answer (score 0):

you can use % operator to get it's mod. get x % 10 and check if result of mod between 0 and 5. it can be faster than that.